# How to get the content of a textblock and show it multiple times?

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I am trying to make a program that helps me with checking on which lines there are errors on an arma 3 server. It currently looks like this:

[image]

I have a few problems. Every time I mark a "bug" and press the show button it comes up with this: [image]

How do i get the content of the textbox? This is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public double output = 0;
    public string test1 = "";
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textOutput.Text = output.ToString();
        textBugs.Text = test1;
    }

    private void buttonDecrease_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        output--;
        textOutput.Text = output.ToString();
    }

    private void buttonIncrease_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        output++;
        textOutput.Text = output.ToString();
    }

    private void buttonReset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        output = 0;
        test1 = "N/A";
        textOutput.Text = output.ToString();
        textBugs.Text = test1;
    }

    private void buttonBug_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        test1 += textBugs.ContentStart.ToString();
    }

    private void buttonShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBugs.Text = test1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `textBugs`? A standard WPF text field? And does `test1` contain the string that you want to be displayed when `buttonShow_Click` is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the problem.

```
test1 += textBugs.ContentStart.ToString();
```

`ContentStart` is a property on a `RichTextBox` with the type `TextPointer`. You're just assigning the string representation of this type to the string `test1`.

To get the plain text from the RTB:

```
test1 += textBugs.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things need to be addressed. What is in the output function that is causing the behavioral error? The other is consider changing the textbox to have an assignment of an int. That way you can increment the variable by only one and then assign it to the textbox afterward. In any case, the `labelName.Text =` is correct way to change the display in your windows form.